# problems with overlapping div tags in cas3

Tags: css, tags, overlapping

I'm working on a new template for a project, and there's one thing I can't seeme to get right.
I want a box to overlap another box, and stay there regardless of the size of the screen. So far I've got the two big boxes i place, but the third(marked with gray, just keeps bouncing around. Any suggestions?
I've added a link to a picture, hope someone understands what I want to do.
http://folk.uio.no/paulkj/Benoit/csstroubble.jpg

Thanks!

Code:

```
body{
    background-color: #2F2727;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

}
#wrapper{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#header {
    width:900px;
    height:100px;
    margin:50px auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}   

#maincontent{
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 2px solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I am probably being stupid right now and overlooked a detail, but where is the css for the grey box?

Comment: The grey box was drawn in to let you see what i want to do. I'm sorry I didn't specify that. I don't know how to get the grey box to stan on the maincontent div regardless of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an higher z-index for your gray box. Refer to this

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

remember to also declare the position property for your gray box or the z-index will not work